# Why is this weird flickering vertical line appearing at left and right of the image?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transitions, css-transforms

[image]

A weird vertical line is appearing on the left and right side of the circular image on hovering. I am really not understanding why this has happened. This problem is not solving and its bothering too much.I use VSCode as code editor, chrome latest version as browser and windows 7 premium OS.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="story">
        <figure class="story__shape">
            <img src="img/nat-8.jpg" alt="Person on a tour" class="story__img">
            <figcaption class="story__caption">Mary Smith</figcaption>
        </figure>
            <div class="story__text">
               <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">I had the best week ever with my family</h3>
               <p>I had such a wonderful experience with you. Your co-ordination and time management is the best thing I felt. I found that you guys give value to the people not for the money. It is so good that you are following the rules strictly when it comes for negative things. Looking forward to have many more trips.</p>
             </div>
    </div>
```

Sass CSS(SCSS):

```
.story{

width: 75%;
margin: 0 auto;
box-shadow: 0 3rem 6rem rgba( $color-black, .1);
background-color: $color-white;
padding: 6rem;
padding-left: 9rem;
font-size: $default-font-size;
transform: skewX(-12deg);

&__shape{
    height: 15rem;
    width: 15rem;
    float: left;
    -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);

    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);

    transform: translateX(-3rem) skewX(12deg);
    position: relative;
}

&__img{
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-4rem) scale(1.4);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .5s;
}

&__text{
    transform: skewX(12deg);
}

&__caption{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 20%);
    color: $color-white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

&:hover &__caption{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

&:hover &__img{
    transform:translateX(-4rem) scale(1);
    filter: blur(3px) brightness(80%);
}   }//end of .story class
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe what browser and OS you are using? This is often very useful info when asking questions about CSS rendering.

Comment: I use VSCode as code editor, Chrome for browser and windows 7 os

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you determine a root cause and solution?

Answer (score 1):

try using overflow:hidden in the &__shape selector

Comment: did you attempt to use your suggested code? The answer should be an answer, not a suggestion.

Comment: Had a similar issue with animated block using an svg clip path. Few hours later and overflow: hidden was the winner. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

cause it's not matching with the background, try using a transparent image

Comment: Tried it but its still there.